# Moving sprite on a predefined path using ccTouchesMoved

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, touch, ccsprite, catmull-rom-curve

I am trying to move the sprite on the path which I define for, by Moving the touch. But I am unable to exact same as the CCCatmullRomBy Action which is predefined in cocos2D. Please suggest me how would I do it.

For more understanding lets assume a car having a road and I want to move the car using touch on the road. The road is zig zag like CCCatmullRomBy with tension 0

Thank you in advance.